# How can I call the connection of a SMTP server outside the function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

I wanted to send multiple messages with one connection using SMTPLIB, but I wanted to create a connection and send the messages dynamically.

I was wondering what i've done wrong, beucase many other libs can hold its connection.

```
import smtplib

def connect():
    cred = {
            'uid': 'xxxxxxx@hotmail.com',
            'pwd': 'xxxxxxx'
            }
    
    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.live.com', 587) as smtp:
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls() #TLS used to encrypt the message
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.login(cred['uid'], 
                   cred['pwd'])
        
    return smtp

smtp = connect()

smtp.send_message( -Some generic message-)
```

Error : SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first

Comment: You are using `with` context, the connection would get closed as soon as you exit out of the `with` context. Try without the `with` syntax.

Comment: Be sure to do capture exceptions in subsequent `send_message` calls and you might have to `connect()` again.